`du` reports wildly different sizes for the same folder depending on arguments
While working on a Seafile server migration, I noticed my rsync of the data took quite a bit longer than I calculated it should. I ended up noticing that some of the directories were already bigger on the receiving end than on the sending end, and investigating further on the sending server, I saw this:
root@skellige:/srv/docker/seafile/data/seafile/seafile-data/storage/blocks# du -hsx */
[...]
3.6G    98574821-b158-428e-952b-b3f4db8e3035/
[...]

root@skellige:/srv/docker/seafile/data/seafile/seafile-data/storage/blocks# for dir in * ; do du -hsx "$dir" ; done
[...]
287G    98574821-b158-428e-952b-b3f4db8e3035/
[...]

I did find similar SE threads before posting this but their accepted answers usually involved copying the data across servers/filesystems, different block sizes, ...
This is the exact same directory, same data, same server, same terminal/shell, a few seconds apart. These results are consistent across time and multiple tests. Given the behaviour of my rsync, it seems the correct value is the one where I loop over the directories myself.
Most of the other directories I've hidden in the output report the same sizes for both methods. Some report differences but minor, in the same order of magnitude. This one specific directory is a pretty big outlier.
The server is a few years old, it's not running the freshest kernel, in case it could be related.
root@skellige:/srv/docker/seafile/data/seafile/seafile-data/storage/blocks# uname -r
4.15.0-167-generic

How can we explain such a big difference ? Why does du report such a small size when running it on all directories at once ?
